# Question about power series involving i and complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help with just about every part of this homework question.

To start with, did I do parts A and B correctly?

Consider the power series f(z) = sum from n=1 to infinity of $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(z-(1+i))^{n}}{n}$

A) identify the center of the series.
     I plugged in n =1 and got z-1+i

B) use the ratio test to find the radius of convergence. Here's my work.  [image: question image]

C) Graph the center and radius on the Argand plane. I can do this once I answer parts A and B correctly.

D) what happens at the "endpoints"?

Comment: The picture is too small to see...

Comment: Alright guys I typed out all the stuff. Thanks for not giving up on me here or down voting.

Comment: Any way I can edit this to receive help?! @KittyL

Answer (score 1):

(A) The center should be a point, not a function, in this case, $1+i$.

(B) You should use absolute values on both top and bottom. And set the answer to be less than $1$. Hence the radius is $1$.

(D) It does not converge at the boundary points.